# Mssql query issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE b
SET b.point = b.point + 5
FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a  ON a.[user] = b.[user]
WHERE  a.requirement = 1
```

This is the query I use at the moment for a function, I do not have high knowledge on MSSQL queries...

I wanted to limit it a bit more, like `a.requirement` is equal 1 but there are more than 5 results from same source with `a.requirement` 1....

How could I make it so `b.point + 5` is only to 2 results only from the same source?

And another line to allow some sources to be exceeded over the limit... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does tableB look like before and what do you want it to look like after the update?

Answer (score 0):

For simple way instead of changing query use
SET ROWCOUNT 2;

Answer (score -1):

You are join tableB and tableA using ON clause, it's ok. But then you need to relate this tableB+tableA join with 'b' using a WHERE clause.

Maybe you want this...

```
UPDATE tableB
SET tableB.point = tableB.point + 5
FROM tableA ON tableA.[user] = tableB.[user] 
WHERE tableA.requirement = 1
```

Try not use alias on table names.

Comment: That's probably not what the asker wants, not least because it gives a syntax error (`FROM tableA ON WHERE`??)

Comment: You were right. There was na error, but now I edited and it's all ok. Sorry and thanks.